# How to get OpenVPN to listen to tcp/ipv4 and tcp/ipv6?

Tags: openvpn

I am using OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu.

```
[root@server sysconfig]# cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf

proto tcp-server
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
secret static.key
```

netstat says it is listening to tcp4, but not to tcp6.  How can I get it to listen to both protocols?

This question is in regard to a tcp configuration; not udp: [OpenVPN with mixed ipv4 and ipv6 clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/651832/openvpn-with-mixed-ipv4-and-ipv6-clients)

Comment: Try `proto udp6` or `proto tcp6`?

Comment: Changing proto tcp-server to proto udp6 results in netstat stating that it is listening for udp and IPv6 - but not udp and IPv4.

Comment: Right, if it is listening on IPv6, it will work for both.  Or at least it works for both on my system.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in the configuration that will get it to listen on IPv6 and IPv4.